# How to query multiply 2 cell for each row using Realm?

Tags: realm

i have one table which has two fields quantity and price , i want to multiply both fields value:
here is what i want which is possible using MYSQL

```
Quantity| Price | Total

6       |   2  |  null // should be 12
2       |  10   |  null // should be 20
```

Above can be done using

```
SELECT 
    quantity, Price, 
    quantity* Price as 'Total' 
FROM myTable
```

i want the same result using realm query .. how can i achieve this ..Any help will be appriciated .. 
Thank you.

Comment: which platform? Android or Swift or React-Native or...?

Comment: for android....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Realm for Android, you'd need to add a new field, and custom setters.

This solution is supported 0.88.0+

```
public class Something extends RealmObject {
    private long quantity;
    private long price;
    private long total;

    public long getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public long getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setQuantity(long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.total = this.quantity * this price;
    }

    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.total = this.quantity * this.price;
    }

    public void setTotal(long total) { // preferably don't use
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

Comment: This issue is very similar to [this github help issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3378)

Comment: Whoops I multiplied by total instead of price. Fixed it though

Comment: @Mehdico I am aware that the proposed solution is a workaround, but Realm doesn't support projections, and the Realm-Java API even less so.